# Error installing while installing unf_ext

Tags: ruby, macos

I installed MacOS High Sierra yesterday, and I was testing my ruby code and it was failing due to one of my gems not being installed. I tried installing it today and got this back:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using bundler 1.15.4
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.4


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.

  Password: 
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.4 with native extensions
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using net-http-digest_auth 1.4.1
Using net-http-persistent 2.9.4
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using ntlm-http 0.1.1
Using webrobots 0.1.2
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/private/var/folders/lq/mdp176gx3b90j7_mvygpydmr0000gn/T/bundler20170927-4407-1gh3fizunf_ext-0.0.7.4/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20170927-4407-1twnwgt.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-static-libstdc++
    --without-static-libstdc++
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in
`try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:535:in
`block in try_link0'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in
`mktmpdir'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:532:in
`try_link0'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in
`try_link'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in
`try_func'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:997:in
`block in have_library'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in
`block in checking_for'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in
`block (2 levels) in postpone'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in
`open'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in
`block in postpone'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in
`open'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in
`postpone'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in
`checking_for'
from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:992:in
`have_library'
    from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/var/folders/lq/mdp176gx3b90j7_mvygpydmr0000gn/T/bundler20170927-4407-1gh3fizunf_ext-0.0.7.4/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/folders/lq/mdp176gx3b90j7_mvygpydmr0000gn/T/bundler20170927-4407-1gh3fizunf_ext-0.0.7.4/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4
for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/lq/mdp176gx3b90j7_mvygpydmr0000gn/T/bundler20170927-4407-1gh3fizunf_ext-0.0.7.4/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.4), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mechanize was resolved to 2.7.5, which depends on
    http-cookie was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
      domain_name was resolved to 0.5.20170404, which depends on
        unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
          unf_ext
```

And then when I try and install unf_ext this happends

```
sudo gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing unf_ext:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170927-4629-13u5zrr.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-static-libstdc++
    --without-static-libstdc++
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:535:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:532:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in `try_func'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:997:in `block in have_library'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:992:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/gem_make.out
```

I have no idea what the issue is. I installed ruby and rbenv, but as soon as I installed the new MacOs I was unable to install any gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied out the "extconf.rb" to my working folder and run "ruby extconf.rb" again, got a mkmf.log, turned out it was a missing "ruby/config.h". Then the problem was fixed by "xcode-select --install". See:

[macOS Mojave 'ruby/config.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135863/macos-mojave-ruby-config-h-file-not-found)

My machine runs 10.13.6 macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you the error, you just need to pick through the output.

```
checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

`extconf.rb` is the script that configures a gem for native compilation, here it's checking a pretty basic requirement: can you compile a C++ executable? And it fails. A bit later it repeats this

```
mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

`mkmf.rb` is a [stdlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html) used by `extconf.rb` to test the capabilities of your compiler and then output a suitable makefile for building the extension. It's repeating that it couldn't even build a C++ executable (let alone check for any specific capability).

So either you don't have a C++ compiler installed or your paths aren't set up in a way that Ruby can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically the same condition as OP (OSX) but I was getting the same error while creating/building an Ubuntu based docker container image. Thanks to [this answer by Max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457070/130639), I fixed it by making sure that `g++` was installed along-side `build-essential`

My Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM ubuntu:jammy

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:/usr/local/bin"
ARG USER=${user:-ruby}
ENV USER=$USER
ENV HOME=/home/$USER

WORKDIR /var/tmp

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y bash git curl ca-certificates \
                build-essential unzip libffi-dev sudo libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
                g++ && \
    curl -sL -o "awscliv2.zip" "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install && \
    groupadd admin && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash $USER -G admin

# set passwd secretly
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=user_passwd < /run/secrets/user_passwd chpasswd

RUN chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME && \
    chown -R $USER:$USER /var/tmp/*

USER ${USER}
ENV PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims"

RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/HEAD/bin/rbenv-installer | bash && \
    eval "$(rbenv init - bash)" || true && \
    curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/HEAD/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash && \
    rbenv install 3.1.2 && \
    rbenv global 3.1.2

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/bundle && \
    chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/local/bundle

USER ${USER}
RUN rbenv init > $HOME/.bashrc 2>&1 || true
#RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - bash)"' > $HOME/.bashrc

WORKDIR /my-operator

COPY . .

RUN gem install bundler && \
    bundler

USER root
RUN apt remove -y --purge build-essential git g++ libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev && \
    apt autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/tmp/* /root/go

USER ${USER}
CMD ["bin/console"]
```