# macOS Mojave 'ruby/config.h' file not found

Tags: ruby, vim, macos-mojave

When I try to build vim(8.1.0509) with ruby support(--enable-rubyinterp) on macOS Mojave(10.14.1) I get error:

```
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error:
      'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
```

I have installed Xcode 10.1.

```
xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 174):

**Note:** this workaround works, but you can't just copy/paste paths blindly. Instead, look at the error installation gave you. It will say something like

> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/mkmf.log

So open the log it mentions, and see what it can't find. It will tell you the correct versions of `MacOSX__._.sdk` and `universal-darwin-__` you need to link

**Catalina, Big Sur, etc. (As of 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023)**

UPDATE: This workaround still works as of 2023. For the commands below, please change version string (e.g., 11.1, ruby 2.6, universal-darwin20, etc.) accordingly to your macOS version environment.

---

Recent versions of macOS and Xcode (e.g. Catalina 10.15 and Xcode 12.2) have this broken. Reinstalling Xcode and `xcode-select --install` did not help for me at all (the solutions already posted seem to be outdated). I did not want to use `rvm` because it may cause some annoying problems.

I did a workaround by manually making a symbolic link:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby
ln -sf ../../../../Headers/ruby/config.h
```

where `ruby/config.h` can be found at:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/Headers/ruby/config.h`.

You should change SDK versions (e.g. 11.1 in the above example) accordingly to your current xcode installation.

It is also very likely that one runs into another error where `.../universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h` cannot be found ([Commonmarker gem cannot be installed (needed for jekyll) macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729369/commonmarker-gem-cannot-be-installed-needed-for-jekyll-macos)). It can be quick-fixed as follows:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0
ln -sf universal-darwin20 universal-darwin19
```

If after using this workaround, you get a crash on `pod install` like:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x0000000100f38000

follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70581304/5318223)

Comment: I can only see univeral-darwin20 in my path. can l still run ```ln -sf universal-darwin20 univeral-darwin19```

Comment: Yes that's the reason why you would need to run the command to make a symbolic link `universal-darwin19` to `universal-darwin20` (please note a typo around `universal-darwin19`; thanks Ewan for fix in the original answer).

Comment: Tried installing `rbenv`. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling `xcode tools`. But only this solution worked. Although, I'm seriously contemplating backing up everything and reseting my machine after all this

Comment: This workaround did not work. Need to perform an update in newer versions.

Comment: I ran into a very similar issue with the Xcode 13 beta (not with vim but with a different project). It looks like the files are now inside the `universal-darwin21` folder for Xcode 13 so I had to update the command to be `ln -sf universal-darwin21 universal-darwin19` and also add `ln -sf universal-darwin21 universal-darwin20` to get my project to build.

Comment: This didn't work and the resulted binary crashed. I reverted the changes and suggest against doing this. It's better to install another version of ruby next to the system one and not mangle with the latter as you risk more issues in the future.

Comment: Getting `Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -c lib/jekyll/commands/doctor.rb.   (NoMethodError) undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: This is a good technique but to update & simplify: `cd $(xcode-select -p)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/include/ruby-2.*`, then see what `universal-darwin*/` directory (directories?) you have, then make a symlink to it with a lower version number `20` or `21` as needed, e.g. `sudo ln -s universal-darwin21 universal-darwin20`.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you very much. On my BigSur I ran `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/` then ´sudo ln -sf ../../../../Headers/ruby/config.h` followed by `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0` and a `sudo ln -sf universal-darwin21 universal-darwin20`

Comment: The final command should be
`ln -sf universal-darwin[x] universal-darwin[x-1]` where x is the version that exists at the .../include/ruby-2.6.0 path.

For me it was `ln -sf universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21`

Comment: I have macos Monterey and I don't have `Xcode.app` inside `Applications`, instead this path worked for me `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/` and also change the symlink to `ln -s universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21`

Comment: It's incredible! You've saved my day one more time! I come to your answer again and again and I'm happy that it resolves my issues!

Answer (score 127):

### macOS Catalina

Issue reappeared in Catalina and I wasn't able to spot this package in the Developer SDK. Until better solution found, I was able to workaround this with rubyenv: https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys/issues/198#issuecomment-510909030

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile 
rbenv install 2.6.3
rbenv global 2.6.3
```

### Mojave and older

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194299/2105993

```
xcode-select --install
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @maksimr as it does exactly what fixes the problem without completely reinstalling macOS

Comment: Seems promising until the warning: "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS and may fail to install. [...] may damage your system [...]". I am just going to try asdf ( https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf), which seems to have ruby in its module list.

Comment: With asdf ruby, gem wants to install packages into the ruby 2.3 system folder, so I stopped trying this. This seemed wrong, and I do not want to use sudo. Homebrew has ruby, and when running using the complete path to its gem utility, as it is by default not activated, my problematic gem could be installed (without sudo, yay).

Comment: The first cmd alone fixed the issue in my case.  Not sure if it's related to how the 1st cmd works currently, but there was no .pkg file for me to open after the install was complete.  After completing the 1st step, this command worked successfully: `sudo gem install cocoapods` - Thank you

Comment: for me 
`brew install ruby`, then
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"`
solved the issue (which was `sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7'`)

Answer (score 81):

**On macOS Catalina**
After installing and uninstalling the developer tools multiple times, this is the only thing that worked for me:

> First install the Ruby Version Manager rvm:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

> Then install the latest version of ruby:

```
rvm install ruby-2.7.2
```

> Finally try again to install the cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

(from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65033418/3605761)

edit: may need `rvm reinstall ruby-2.7.2` instead of `rvm install ruby-2.7.2` at step 2.

edit2: @greg-dubicki mentioned swapping ruby-2.7.2 for ruby-3.0.3: rvm install ruby-3.0.3 and then making it the default: rvm --default use 3.0.3 they also mentioned: As an extra benefit, thanks to the switch from the outdated system Ruby 2 to a current version 3, you will get up to 3 x better performance.

Comment: make sure u use the correct version of ruby after install : `ruby --version` to check version and `rvm use 2.7.2` to set

Comment: @greg-dubicki mentioned swapping ruby-2.7.2 for ruby-3.0.3:   
`rvm install ruby-3.0.3`  
and then making it the default:  
`rvm --default use 3.0.3`  

they also mentioned:  
As an extra benefit, thanks to the switch from the outdated system Ruby 2 to a current version 3, you will get up to 3 x better performance.

Comment: Thankyou! This is the only response that worked for me. Updated to 3.1.0 set version with `rvm use 3.1.0`

Comment: Thanks, installed `rvm install ruby-3.1.2` in 2022

Comment: For Monterey xCode 14.2 run: ```rvm install ruby-3.0.6 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)```

Answer (score 22):

If you are facing this issue in Mac Big Sur, reinstalling `CommandLineTools` can fix this issue.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

xcode-select --install
```

Comment: This took a long time and installed an older version of CommandLineTools. Maybe that was the point(!) but I didn't realize that, let Software Update update it, and the result didn't fix the problem. The symlink approach in the top answer worked, with adjustments.

Answer (score 20):

I had the exact same problem. Could not install gems with native extensions. Running

```
$ open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

failed, because the file did not exist. Looks like Mojave can break the commandline tools.

I fixed it by removing the Xcode commandline tools, installing them again and then installing the missing headers:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
$ open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Answer (score 14):

This is because some versions of Xcode don't have the macOS SDK for the OS it's running on, when compiling native extension of gem.

make sure Xcode version and macOS version match each other:

- macOS 10.15: Xcode < 12.2
- macOS 11: Xcode >= 12.2, <= 13.0
- macOS 12: Xcode >= 13.1, <= 14.0
- macOS 13: Xcode >= 14.1, < 15.0
- macOS 14: Xcode >= 15.0

---

P.S. I found a similar list in the doc of MacPorts, which may be more  up to date. (search `13.1 or later for Monterey` in https://www.macports.org/install.php)

Comment: It also appears this is an issue with macOS Ventura; it requires Xcode 14.1.

Answer (score 6):

### **MacOS Ventura 13.6**

Went through this non-sense while trying to bootstrap a React Native project using the following script:  `npx react-native@latest init <Project Name>` as per official documentation. Was experiencing the following error: `fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found` despite a fresh install of xcode and command line tools following the update to Ventura 13.6.

**Solution:**

1. Navigate to the problematic folder:

   ```
   cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby
   ```
2. Copy the missing header file:

   ```
   sudo cp ../../../../Headers/ruby/config.h .
   ```
3. Rename the the "universal-darwin23" folder to "universal-darwin22" :

   ```
   sudo mv /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin23/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin22/
   ```
4. Install "activesupport" gem:

   ```
   sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6
   ```
5. Manually install cocoapods:

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```

Now it finally works as intended. It looks some fellow developer did something wrong at some point.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

**On macOS Catalina**
If multiple versions of xcode are installed,xcode12/xcode12.4 etc.Please try to change your xcode command line tools in xcode preferences. It may works!!!

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the above and I eventually got it working with this little 'gem', pardon the pun.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

From https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668456

Comment: Hi, using this command I was able to install cocoapods 1.8.4. But I need to upgrade the version. Using this code with latest version does not work again! Can you please suggest anything?

Answer (score 3):

I did the similar things to Jongwook Choi with the following environment and problem as a case reference.

I am using macOS 12.6.2.
The problem arises when I try to install `cocoapods` by running `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

After reading the suggested logs in the terminal feedback and reading the source code it is referring to, it is obviously a bug of the builtin files in macOS 12.6.2.

In my case, I do the followings and the `cocoapods` can be installed successfully.

Original error

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
```

Action 1

```
The file `config.h` is missing. So I build the symbolink in the folder 

cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin22/ruby/config.h
```

The second one is referring to a folder called `universal-darwin21`.
However, I try to use `uname -r` and got `21.6` so I think it is obviously does not hurt to create a symbolink of "universal-darwin21" to resolve the problem.

Original error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin21/ruby/config.h', needed by `AbstractMemory.o'.  Stop.
```

Action 2

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21
```

After that, the installation runs successfully.
However, if reading the log file
`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out`

It is still outing some warnings, if study those warnings, will find missing folders which is obviously missing and is the problem of the system files/folders rather than anything wrong with the user actions.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find this mentioned above, and I'm not sure if that's a universal solution. Mentioning this as this may be still useful.

At least with Xcode 14/macOS 13/12, it's possible to use stock Ruby, without messing up with symlinks, provided that macOS command line tools package is installed on the host. The thing is that command line tools package bundles SDKs for most recent versions of macOS, and most notably, the one matching the host (from what I can see, that SDK has the "correct" name for the directory containing ruby/config.h). Then it's just a matter of overriding SDKROOT in the environment (this is the most crucial thing), to point all the low-level tools like clang to the custom root matching the "correct" version of SDK. (Without override, it would still use the default SDK bundled with the tools, that may or not match the version of macOS running on the host).

```
macos_major_vers=$(sw_vers -productVersion | sed 's/^\([^.]*\)\..*$/\1/') # e.g. 12
export SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX"$macos_major_vers".sdk

# ... build commands for Ruby gems go here.
```

Comment: This worked for me and I chose this approach as I didn't want to mess around with installing Xcode (just CommandLineTools). I did tweak the first line to be a little easier for me to understand:

`local macos_major_version=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F. '{print $1}')`

Answer (score 2):

for me it worked "rvm install ruby" (not with brew) and then doing steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622113/1459573):

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
```

and then

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

After all this, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**2021 Advice**
If you are able, updating to macOS Big Sur and then updating Xcode will also fix the issue.

Just tested on updating 10.15 -> 11.2.3 for macOS.
And 12.4 for Xcode.

Comment: Simply upgrading macOS actually didn't work for me on at least two different macs I have.

Comment: @JongwookChoi you need to update Xcode also as that does something to the Ruby scripts or at least points to the "correct" area

Answer (score 1):

## MacOS Big Sur Beta 8

try this:

1. install rbenv

- `git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`
- `cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src`
- Add ~/.rbenv/bin to your $PATH for access to the rbenv command-line utility.
  see: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout
- make sure `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"` was added to your $PATH

2. `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develope`
3. `gem install cocoapods` should work like a charm!

Comment: this didn't solve my problem but the one from Nov 20 '18  did.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Monteray 12.6.5 I fixed this cocoapod Unity error by following a path modified version to [macOS Mojave 'ruby/config.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135863/macos-mojave-ruby-config-h-file-not-found/76224631#comment127542869_65481787) comment:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/
```

then

```
sudo ln -sf ../../../../Headers/ruby/config.h
```

followed by

```
cd 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 and a sudo ln -sf universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21
```

Then the cocoapod installation succeeded.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me on Monteray. I had to only replace MacOSX12.1.sdk to MacOSX13.1.sdk in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Error thrown in my case was

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What I noticed here is that I was on MacOs version 13.5 while the error message above indicated MacOS 14. My Xcode version was 15.

I updated to MacOS Sonoma which is version 14 and that resolved my issue.

Issue seems to be have been caused by some version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew has a cask for Cocoapods.

Try,

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was different from - [Yosemite upgrade broke ruby.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434642/yosemite-upgrade-broke-ruby-h)

As you can see in the description of the problem it's *System*'s ruby, not Xcode's ruby so reinstall Xcode or symlink didn't help here.

**Answer:**
I have [reinstalled macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) without losing any data and this fixed the problem.

Comment: I was running into this issue when trying to install Command-T for macvim and was worried I needed to drop the big bomb of reinstalling Mojave. Instead, I found the System ruby was actually Ruby 2.3.7 (Macvim was built against this System ruby, version 2.3.7), and I installed ruby 2.3.7 using rbenv. Once that was installed and set as my default ruby, I could install Command-T like normal. Might still need to consider reinstalling Mojave at a later date, but installing Ruby 2.3.7 via rbenv helped me get things running without doing that now. I hope this helps someone else in this situation.

Comment: ReDetection solution worked and i also used Systems Ruby. I mean thats what the download is for right? Headers for  Mac OS X.

Comment: In my case /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools doesn't contain Packages folder. As I wrote above reinstall Mojave was a solution (You can reinstall it without losing data)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing eventmachine 1.2.7, this worked for me (macOS 10.15.5):

(I use `fish`)

1. `brew install ruby`
2. Add the following `~/.config/fish/config.fish` (without `fish`, just add these to path)

   1. `fish_add_path /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin`
   2. `fish_add_path /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin`
3. `set -gx CPPFLAGS "-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"`
4. `set -gx LDFLAGS "-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"`
5. `set -gx PKG_CONFIG_PATH "/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"`
6. `sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

The `set -gx` commands I got after installing ruby thru brew.

I tried reinstalling the Xcode tools (12.3 as I can't upgrade to Big Sur just yet) and re-accepting agreement, but that didn't change anything

---

One note is that this was from installing `eventmachine 1.2.7`. The log error I got referenced this path as one of its flags:

```sh
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I
```

Note that it was trying to look in `.../MacOSX11.1.sdk/...`, but I have 10.15.5. Even setting `CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, PKG_CONFIG_PATH` manually did not work as I was using either system ruby or whatever `rbenv` had, but I was too frustrated to dig deeper down that particular rabbit hole. So, I reinstalled w/ brew's ruby!

Answer (score 0):

This is not cocoa pod issue, It is related to the older version of ruby.
Simply follow the below steps :

1. rvm install "ruby-3.0.0"
2. sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after uninstalling an older version of Xcode. Typically, I install into /Applications/Xcode-13.2.1.app for example. However, `xcode-select -p` still showed it was pointing to an older version.

I just ran `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-13.2.1.app` and everything started working correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error as part of `bundle install`, see below -

I couldn't get any of the posted solutions to work. What worked for me was installing the specified bundler version from the logs. For example, my Console was warning me about mismatching bundler version and I ran `gem install bundler:2.2.32` to fix it which then fixed the `bundle install` command for me. In my case, i was using rvm and ruby version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

### MacOS Sonoma

These steps fixed my issue:

- Update XCode
- Install manually CocoaPods `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- [Optional] If it shows an error related to activesupport then install manually `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6`

Ruby version `2.6.10.210`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using rbenv (on Catalina) and none of the solutions I found here (or elsewhere) worked for me. Ultimately what fixed my environment was pointing `rbenv global` to a specific version of ruby instead of `system`:

```
$ rbenv global 2.6.3
```

This was the state of my env while `gem install` was failing:

```
$ gem env home
=> /Users/ryanc/.gem

$ which gem
=> /Users/ryanc/.rbenv/shims/gem

$ which ruby
=> /Users/ryanc/.rbenv/shims/ruby

$ ruby -v
=> ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

$ rbenv local
=> rbenv: no local version configured for this directory

$ rbenv global
=> system

$ rbenv which ruby
=> /usr/bin/ruby
```

The result of `rbenv which ruby` was the key. I decided to run `rbenv global 2.6.3` and suddenly I could install gems again. Here's the new state of things:

```
$ ruby -v
=> ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin19]

$ rbenv global
=> 2.6.3

$ rbenv which ruby
=> /Users/ryanc/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case (Catalina 10.15.7) simply re-installying `ruby` with `homebrew` fixed it. No need to install `rvm` or `rubyenv`.

Comment: Note: Homebrew ruby is a "different" one than the system ruby, and pointing to the 'right' ruby for other downstream build process can be tricky. For example, homebrew refuses to link macOS provided ruby, so you'll need to configure PATH, LDFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, and pkgconfig properly, which often goes like a mess and does not work as smooth as expected.

Answer (score -1):

it's about your ruby version or bad installation.
you can install new ruby version with rvm

first install rvm with bellow command

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

then close and reopen terminal or use command source [you mac bash file like .zshrc or .bashrrc] to load rvm command

next install new ruby version with bellow command

> rvm install ruby-2.7.2

now you should use new version of ruby and install last version of cocoapods
do this steps:

- check ruby version
- check ruby version with ruby -v command
- if your ruby version not 2.7.2 use 'rvm use 2.7.2' command to switch
  on new ruby
- then install cocoapods with 'sudo gem install cocoapods' command

for check new pods version use 'gem which cocoapods' command.

Comment: for set new ruby as default ruby
use 'rvm --default use 2.7.2' command

Answer (score -2):

I'm encountered with the same problem a moment ago, and the following **works** for me.

```
brew install rbenv
# To get the latest stable version of ruby
rbenv install --list
# 3.1.1 is the latest version
rbenv install 3.1.1 && rbenv global 3.1.1
```

Do as installation tips of the previous step:
`vim ~/.zhrc` and append `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"`; finally, restart your term to make the line take effect.

I prefers not to make change under `/Applications/Xcode.app` since everything done will be lost after upgrading Xcode.

By the way, `rbenv install --list` tells all stable versions of ruby, and I choose the latest. You could try earlier ruby version that works for you.