# Commonmarker gem cannot be installed (needed for jekyll) macos

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

what do I have to do, is there a problem with dependencies? How do I fix those? I am on catalina.

I repeatedly get this error and have already looked for the directory.. doesn't exist.

```
sudo bundle update
Password:
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.......
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby
version:
  In Gemfile:
    github-pages was resolved to 1, which depends on
      Ruby (~> 1.9.3)

jekyll-feed (~> 0.12) was resolved to 0.13.0, which
depends on
      Ruby (>= 2.3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem
"commonmarker":
  In Gemfile:
    commonmarker (~> 0.21.0)

    github-pages was resolved to 203, which depends on
jekyll-commonmark-ghpages (= 0.1.6) was resolved
to 0.1.6, which depends on
        commonmarker (~> 0.17.6)
➜  blog git:(gh-pages) ✗ sudo gem install commonmarker
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing commonmarker:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commonmarker-0.21.0/ext/commonmarker
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200903-9124-19bmbh8.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commonmarker-0.21.0/ext/commonmarker
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commonmarker-0.21.0/ext/commonmarker
make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h', needed by `arena.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commonmarker-0.21.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/commonmarker-0.21.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: It's a problem building native extensions. Do you have Xcode and the command-line add-on installed, with the EULA accepted?

Comment: `github-pages was resolved to 1, which depends on Ruby (~> 1.9.3)` is another major problem. version 1 was released in 2013 -- use a newer version of the gem.

Comment: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h`, in my case `universal-darwin19` didn't exist but `universal-darwin20` did. Make a symbolic link to `universal-darwin20` named `universal-darwin19`

Answer (score 19):

Sam's comments are correct. XCode's ruby framework is broken. A workaround is to make a symbolic link:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0
ln -sf universal-darwin20 universal-darwin19
```

With this, I was able to successfully build all the native extensions.

Note: You should change your path segment `MacOSX11.1.sdk` according to your local Xcode SDK installation.

Comment: This is correct, but should be `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0
ln -sf universal-darwin20 universal-darwin19`

Comment: ^ universal-darwin19 is misspelled in the original answer

Comment: Fixed the typo, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Works, with a little Change on MacOS Monterey: `cd` into `MacOSX13.1.sdk` instead: `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/` and then run `sudo ln -sf universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21` (without sudo it doesn't work).

Answer (score 6):

For those on MacOS *without XCode* and only command line tools installed:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0
sudo ln -sf universal-darwin20 universal-darwin21
```

...tweaking the `MacOSX11.3.sdk` segment in the path if need be.

Comment: This answered worked for me instead of the one above due to the symbolic link creation.  The target was expecting `universal-darwin21` but only `universal-darwin19` existed.

`MacOSX10.15.sdk`

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem with a different gem; I found that

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h`

didn't exist, but

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin20/ruby/config.h`

did exist - i.e. `universal-darwin20` rather than `universal-darwin19`.

If I ran my install command using a newer version of Ruby, it worked.

Exactly how to do this will differ for different setups.  I was using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), so ran `rbenv local 2.6.6` before the install command.

You can read more about running multiple Ruby versions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/340490/how-to-install-and-use-different-versions-of-ruby), or you could just run a single Ruby version but try upgrading it to a newer version (e.g. `brew upgrade ruby` if you're using Homebrew).

Answer (score 0):

I also needed a symbolic link, but my ruby installation was in a different location (`/Library/Developer/...` vs `/Applications/Xcode.app/...`), for that reason, the commands I used to fix my local github-pages installation were:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/

sudo ln -sf universal-darwin19 universal-darwin20
```

Answer (score -1):

cd path like your log error
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0

and dupplicate and rename folder copy `universal-darwin20` to `universal-darwin19`

now it is working.
You can try higher version ruby or rails. gem support for it