# Make errors while installing byebug gem

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, byebug

I am trying to install byebug and it keeps giving me this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h', needed by `breakpoint.o'.  Stop.
```

I tried to reinstall ruby and it did not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could try installing `rvm` or `rbenv` instead of using your system's ruby.

Comment: i did reinstall ruby with rvm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729369/commonmarker-gem-cannot-be-installed-needed-for-jekyll-macos might be useful for you; it's the same error but a different gem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error!

I just created a symbolic link:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0
ln -sf universal-darwin21 universal-darwin19
```

Now it is working fine.

**Check which universal-darwin you have to point correctly.**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481809/4964553

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me as well!
I had to do
```bash
sudo ln -s universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21
``` on my system.