# Error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `init'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to create a Jekyll project with the [Chirpy theme](https://chirpy.cotes.info/posts/getting-started/) on macOS, and I've completed the steps in [this setup guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/) until where I have to run `bundle`. When I run `bundle`, this happened:

```
$ bundle

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `init' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from [Project Dir]/Gemfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  bundle init
 #
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

#### Gemfile:

```
bundle init

gem "jekyll"
```

#### Versions:

```
$ gem --version
3.0.3

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin19]

$ bundle --version
Bundler version 2.2.17

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H2
```

#### Other Info

- I installed ruby using `rbenv` following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388305/7346633) rather than using the stock ruby from Xcode, because the stock ruby was throwing the `'ruby/config.h' file not found` error.
- I used `gem install --user-install bundler jekyll` to install bundler and jekyll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide is telling you to run the `bundle init` command in terminal. It will generate a Gemfile for you.

But it's just optional, you can create a Gemfile yourself:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll"
```